# add new item in listbox for each click on button vba

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

I have a userform with multiple comboboxes and textboxes that adds new entries to a table whenever the "Enter"-button is clicked. 
A feature I would like to add is to have a listbox that shows the user all the entries they have made. Thus showing a list with all the new entries since the form was loaded, until the user clicks the "Clear"-button. Another feature I would like to add is the capability for the user to select an entry in the listbox, load it back into the form controls, and edit the existing entry (in case they see they have made an error).

I've predefined the listbox with 8 columns (in Properties).
The code I've currently got for the listbox is under the Enter_click event and together with the database code:

```
Private Sub cmdEnter_Click()

Dim LastRow As Range
Dim xxxTable As ListObject

Sheets("abc").ListObjects("xxx").ListRows.Add

'Enter data from form into our new row
Set ProjectsTable = Sheets("abc").ListObjects("xxx")
Set LastRow = xxxTable.ListRows(xxxTable.ListRows.Count).Range

With LastRow
    .Cells(1, 1) = txta.Value
    .Cells(1, 2) = txtb.Value
    .Cells(1, 3) = cboc.Value
    .Cells(1, 4) = txtd.Value
    .Cells(1, 5) = txte.Value
    .Cells(1, 6) = cbof.Value
    .Cells(1, 7) = cbog.Value
    .Cells(1, 8) = txth.Value
End With

 'Inserts data into listbox

With ListBox1

.AddItem
.List(i, 0) = txta.Value
.List(i, 1) = txtb.Value
.List(i, 2) = cboc.Value
.List(i, 3) = txtd.Value
.List(i, 4) = txte.Value
.List(i, 5) = cbof.Value
.List(i, 6) = cbog.Value
.List(i, 7) = txth.Value
    i = i + 1

End With

End Sub
```

While the listbox code adds data to the listbox, it adds only one entry and edits it for each click instead of the desired "add on list".
For the editing, I'm not even sure where to begin.

Would be grateful for some pointers on where to begin to solve my two problems.

Please see image of the userform below for more context:

[image: Userform]

Comment: You are doubling the work. If you add everything immediately to the sheet then you might as well set the `ListBox1.RowSource` to the `ListBox` or table where all the data is stored. Alternatively, you can keep all the changes in the form only and add new items to the `ListBox1` only and once the user is done you write all the changes to the sheet. But making all the changes in both places at once seems (to me at least) to over-complicate things a bit.

Comment: I think you might be running into the limitations of Excel for more robust database entry. I would suggest looking at Access forms, especially split forms (which is what your graphic looks like). Access would easily allow you to see all entries and provide a way to edit. See the following link for more information: [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-split-form-e8eb0efb-2fa6-4315-9d4b-86e79a1fbe1e)

Comment: Ralph you're correct in that I overcomplicate things here :) I didn't however completely get what you are saying: Are you suggesting that I add entries to the listbox first then from the listbox to the sheet in a separate mechanicsm? Or that I simply just use the listbox only to create however large set I want of new entries? (ie enter data directly to the listbox then enter data from the listbox directly to the sheet - I wasn't aware of this possibility)

Comment: James SMith - you are indeed correct. However this is a project I've inherited and I have a relatively short timeline to complete this. If I'm tasked to maintain this database in the long term, switching gradually to Access would definitely be the best way to go.